# How to set http headers for multiple messages in nodered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-red

I am developing a flow that aims to divide a huge message into smaller messages. I have achieved all the logical part for dividing the msg, however, when sending all those small messages to a http response node I get the following error:

> "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

Of couse, I specified the headers in the http response node, but without any success so far.

It's important to mention that I get this error after the 1st small message is sent, so yeah, basically the following messages trigger this error.

Any idea how to resolve this error ?

Things that I've tried so far:

- Specify the headers in the http response.
- Put a function before the response node and specify the headers of the msg in the function itself.

Comment: You can't do chunked encoding with the HTTP response node, it's one input one output

Comment: Therefore... You mean that I cannot set multiple headers in every output ?

Comment: I'm saying you can only send 1 message into the response node or every 1 message input from the request node. You have to set all the headers for that response at the same time.

Comment: @hardillb You should add that as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a Catch node to catch the Exception Errors from the HTTP Response Node. In addition to the Catch node, you can configure a Switch node to Filter out the HTTP_HEADERS_SENT messages to debug other Exception Errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Node-RED HTTP-Response node does not support HTTP Chunked encoding. This means that the entire response needs to be held in the `msg.payload` field of a single input message. That message needs to also originate from a HTTP-In node (it carries the object needed to send the response back).

This also means that Headers need to either be set in the `msg.headers` field of the same object or in the config of the HTTP-Response object.